# Windows 8 IE 11 css not displaying the same as every other brower

Tags: html, css, windows, internet-explorer

![enter image description here][1]So i have created a website that i have tested and it works fine in all major browsers, except for when I am running windows 8. Windows 7works fine but i windows 8 a lot of my css is being affected.

I was wondering if anyone knew a list of things that were different or displayed differently because of this as i really do not want to re write the whole thing!

It appears as though padding might be adding to the height/width properties or something im not quite sure but would appreciate a heads up on any niggly things anyone else has found before i try tearing my css to pieces!

css

```
.whitebox-index {
    background-color: #fff;
    max-width: 1044px;
    min-height: 1055px;
    position: relative;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
       padding: 10px;
}

#banner {
    width: 1024px;
    height: 370px;
    /*margin-bottom: 10px;*/
    position: absolute;
    background-image:url(../images/bannerhomebackground.png);
}
```

In chrome etc this displays as a my white background witha banner at the top and has the even white gap around it but in windows 8 ie this has the 10px gap to the left and top but the right has a 30mm gap.... the width has increased...

Comment: I work on the IE team, and would be happy to help determine the cause. Can you setup a small repro using http://jsfiddle.net?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ca2nh4v1/ @JonathanSampson nothing over the top its just displaying odd

Comment: Although even on the JS fiddle it works odd with the extra red to the right of the banner but it all works fine in my actual website? Am i missing something stupid????

Comment: I am not seeing any major differences. Here's a screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/7G8y5si.png. Do you see the problem on my screen as well?

Comment: I added a screenshot of the differences I am seeing, this is jut the most basic thing i am seeing the rest of the website is even worse!just thought i would start and see if there is a basic problem that could be causing this. @JonathanSampson

Comment: I also noticed that my embedded fonts do not work in Windows 8 IE also.....

Comment: That extra spacing could be caused by something further down the page; it's difficult to tell without having access to the page.

Comment: Crap ok am going to have to go through the whole page to see what it is, cant really post a screen shot of the rest of the page without disclosing too much of the rebrand for the company I work for. but thanks anyway!

Comment: I would be more than happy to take this offline and help you identify the issues that cause IE to render differently. Feel free to email me at josamp@microsoft.com.

Comment: @JonathanSampson I figured it all out! What a nightmare - because i am just viewing files on my local server i had to switch the compatibility settings and now it looks fine so it should be fine when it goes live. I hope. Thanks!

Comment: Happy to hear it's working; if you ever have any questions about compat between IE and other browsers, please don't hesitate to reach out! You can close this question if it's no longer an issue.

Comment: @JonathanSampson I posted the answer so that if someone else is going crazy over why nothing seemed to be logically working they might find the solution here! Thanks heaps.

Comment: Worth noting that this will affect *all* of your intranet sites. You could alternatively use the [`x-ua-compat` meta tag](https://www.modern.ie/en-us/performance/how-to-use-x-ua-compatible) to set the docmode to Edge.

Comment: @JonathanSampson I don't suppose you know a good image/div slider that would be IE9 compatible do you?

Comment: IE 9 has solid support for CSS 2.1 positinioning, and CSS 3 transformations, so just about any prominent slider should work. If you find problems, again, please let me know :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just needed to uncheck "Display intranet sites in Compatibility View" from the Compatibility View Settings menu.

Edit:
Worth noting that this will affect all of your intranet sites. You could alternatively use the x-ua-compat meta tag to set the docmode to Edge. –  Jonathan Sampson